# Configuring Named DNS zones (Centos7), specifically CNAME

Tags: networking, centos, dns

having trouble with some DNS configuration, I have managed to get part of the site working, however adding the prefix 'www', I'm finding a little tricky.

Essentially, what I want is

mysite.net -> IP address 12.0.0.50 (This works fine)
www.mysite.net -> IP address 12.0.0.60 (This is not working)

I would really appreciate some pointers here, I believe my syntax is what is the source of the problem, but having looked at materials online, I haven't been able to find a solution.

Here is my code for my zone.

```
$TTL 1D
$ORIGIN mysite.net.
@       IN SOA  ns1 admin.mysite.net. (
                                    0       ; serial
                                    1D      ; refresh
                                    1H      ; retry
                                    1W      ; expire
                                    3H )    ; minimum
    1D IN NS        ns1
    1D IN A         12.0.0.50
www             CNAME   mysite.net.
www     1D IN A         12.0.0.60
ns1             1D IN A 12.0.0.10
```

www.mysite.net needs to have an A record for 12.0.0.60, and it also needs to be www, hence the reason for the CNAME, but it won't resolve. Any ideas to what I have done wrong here?

Comment: Have also tried www.mysite.net. 1D IN A 12.0.0.60 with no success, I know that it's not possible to have a record with CNAME, but how can I point the www. -> 12.0.0.60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CNAME` is used to create aliases to the same destination, however your domains (`mysite.net` and `www.mysite.net`) do not share the same destination. You must set up two A records:

```
$TTL 1D
$ORIGIN mysite.net.
@      IN SOA  ns1 admin.mysite.net. (
                                    0       ; serial
                                    1D      ; refresh
                                    1H      ; retry
                                    1W      ; expire
                                    3H      ; minimum
       )

@      IN NS        ns1          ; mysite.net is handled by ns1.

@      IN A         12.0.0.50    ; mysite.net is at 12.0.0.50
ns1    IN A         12.0.0.10    ; ns1.mysite.net is at 12.0.0.10
www    IN A         12.0.0.60    ; www.mysite.net is at 12.0.0.60
```

Here, you have three machines available:

- 12.0.0.10, which is hosting the DNS server. It can be reached through ns1.mysite.net.
- 12.0.0.50 which is hosting the first website through mysite.net.
- 12.0.0.60 which is hosting the second website through www.mysite.net.

This configuration should be made on 12.0.0.10, which seems to be your authoritative name server here. However, there is no need for a `CNAME` entry.

However, let's say that now, you want to add the `forum` subdomain, the content for which is hosted on 12.0.0.60, you may use:

```
forum  IN CNAME     www          ; forum is an alias to www (12.0.0.60)
```